# PHP Select user and article and insert new article if no exists

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a script to Add new Data in the DB from the User in SESSION,
But something is wrong...
Please have a look.

i'm trying to get this script done but...

```
     user_id    ....         ...    ...       ...........
     0       | dsadadsa | sadsadsa |asdsad |2017-02-04 01:32:26
```

The user_id still in 0... and should be add the ID of the user...

Can someone help me with this code... I really need to put him right.

```
members:
username | id | password | ...

sessions:
id | user_id | name | ...
```

||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

```
<?php
 require "loginheader.php";


 $host = 'localhost';
 $dbname = 'db_movie';
 $username = 'root';
 $password = '';

 $nam = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
 $se = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sess']);
 $ep = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['episode']); 
 $userID = $_SESSION['username'];



    // Creating...
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Checking connecton...
if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    //Inserting...
    $sql = "INSERT INTO sessions (name, user_id, sess, episode, date) VALUES ('$nam', '$userID', '$se', '$ep', NOW())";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
       echo " You added $nam in to your <a href='../series.php'>Library</a>.";  
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

  $conn->close();


   ?>
```

Comment: This code is highly susceptible to SQL Injection and you should really look into Prepared Statements. escape strings aren't always enough.